# Apple's default java in System folder?

Tags: java

I have removed Apple's default java from System folder.Is there any way to add it again without reinstalling the OS ?

Comment: you could try to just enter `java` in a terminal and the system may prompt you to download it. The second approach would be to just download java 1.7 from [oracle](http://www.java.com/de/download/manual.jsp).

Comment: http://www.java.com/en/download/help/mac_install.xml

Comment: Thanks Daniel.I have done it but Apps like Netbeans and IntelliJ idea couldn'started.I think,it is because they are unable to find the path.Java_home is set to latest jdk and it working fine on Terminal.

Comment: I'm familiar with neither Netbeans nor IntelliJ but in Eclipse you can easily have multiple JDKs (eg. Java 7 and 8, Oracle or OpenJDK). That is to say that, yes, you can also reinstall the JDK if you removed it. Follow @BadSkillz's link.

Comment: Thanks all.
http://support.apple.com/kb/dl1572 this is link to java update for Mac OS X 10.7 or later. @BadSkillz link is for Mac OS X 10.6